# Avoid Page refresh on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this .net page where I have a media player control and a button. The button functionality is to call a stored procedure. I need the page NOT to reload and stop the video when the user clicks the button.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code

watching.aspx

```
<div id="video" runat="server">
    <div id="myElement">
        Loading...
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnWatchlist" runat="server" Text="add to watchlist" onclick="btnWatchlist_Click" />
```

watching.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Watching : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int movieId = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         movieId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
         Movie movie = MovieAccess.GetMovieDetails(movieId);
         startVideo(movie);      
    }
    private void startVideo(Movie movie)
    {
        string moviePath= "data/videos/"+movie.srcPath;
        String script = "<script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('myElement').setup({file: '" + moviePath + "',image: '43.jpg', \"width\": 800,\"height\": 450,});</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "video", script, false);
    }
    protected void btnWatchlist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovieAccess.AddWatchlistMovie(movieId, User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the button HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a client side call (using javascript or the popular jQuery library) to the server. There's plenty of tutorials on google.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Button` inside an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: perhaps include some code to explain what you mean, and also explain why it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(!IsPostBack)
         {
           movieId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
           Movie movie = MovieAccess.GetMovieDetails(movieId);
           startVideo(movie);    
         }  
    }
```